# In Git how can I stage a file I have just diffed without manually specifying the file?

Tags: git, bash

I frequently diff a file, decide it's what I'll stage and then have to run the `git add /long/path/to/file` to manually specify the file.

A usual work flow would go along the lines of:

`git status`

"oooh changes"

`git diff /long/path/to/changed/file`

"Yup, I remember that - commit time!"

`git add /long/path/to/changed/file`

Obviously this isn't the hardest thing in the world to do, it just gets a little tedious. I know I could go into interactive mode too, but that's never really fitted my work flow.

So I'm looking for some magic unix or git command where I can say "Hey, that file I just diffed - stage it please!".

Does something like that exist in either Git or Bash? Or is it something I need to build in a bash script?

Comment: I just double click the path and then paste with middle button :-) Fast enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
git add !$
```

More info: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-call-last-argument-of-preceding-command/

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of bash shell shortcuts. For example, type:

> git add <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> shortcut yanks the arguments from the previous command. You can also repeat it to search for arguments further back in your command history.

#### Bonus material...

If you're up for something more arcane, try the following:

```
[you@home]$ git diff /some/path/to/file
[you@home]$ ^diff^add
```

From the [definitive guide to bash command line history](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/):

> Perhaps the most interesting event
>   designator is the one in form
>   **'^string1^string2^'** which takes the
>   last command, replaces **string1** with
>   **string2** and executes it.

Using `^diff^add`, while amusing, can be a pain to type. And it cannot be used in an alias. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956018/in-git-how-can-i-stage-a-file-i-have-just-diffed-without-manually-specifying-the/4956417#4956417) for an alternative.

Comment: For the record you don't need the trailing ^. You can just do ^diff^add

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to stick to what's stated in the docs, but you're absolutely right. Updated example.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias addiff='fc -s "git diff=git add"'
```

You now have a `addiff` command which, when used after a `git diff`, will covert it to a `git add`.

```
[you@home]$ git diff /some/path/to/file
[you@home]$ addiff
```

[fc](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_107.html) (short for Fix Command) is a bash built-in command. When used without options, it allows you to edit your previous command before re-execution. Using the `-s` options allows one to specify the pattern without having to resort to a text editor.

For a more generic usage of `fc`, add `alias r='fc -s'` to your `.bashrc`. You can then use it as such:

```
[you@home]$ r # repeat the previous command

[you@home]$ r git # repeat the last command containing the word "git"

[you@home]$ r foo=bar # repeat the last command, replace "foo" with "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

`git add .`

This command line adds all new files in the present work directory without specifying file names or file path.

Comment: Can you please provide a link in which more detail is given?